# Maximum Path of a Binary tree not passing all the test cases

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to solve this Leetcode problem: [Binary Tree Maximum Path Sum.](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum) I know there are a lot of SO answers for this question. But I could not find anything related to my issue. So, before diving into the code, I want to give a high-level overview of how I wrote the algorithm.

```
If I am at a particular node, I considered the following cases.
 Case 1: The maximum path is somewhere inside the left subtree (not including the current node)
 Case 2: The maximum path is somewhere inside the right subtree (not including the current node)
 Case 3: The maximum path starts from the current node and ends somewhere in the left subtree
 Case 4: The maximum path starts from the current node and ends somewhere in the right subtree
 Case 5: The maximum path is the current node itself.
 Case 6: The maximum path starts somewhere in the left subtree, goes through the current node, and ends somewhere in the right subtree.
```

And here is the code:

```js
var maxPathSum = function(root) {
    if (root.left === null && root.right === null) {
        return root.val;
    }
    
    // Case 1: Max sum is in the left subtree (not including the root)
    let leftPathSum = 0;
    if (root.left) {
        leftPathSum = maxPathSum(root.left);
    }
     // Case 2: Max sum is in the right subtree (not including the root)
    let rightPathSum = 0;
    if (root.right) {
        rightPathSum = maxPathSum(root.right);
    }
     
    
    // Case 3: root + leftPathSum
    let leftSumWithRoot = leftPathSum + root.val; 
    // Case 4: root + rightPathSum
    let rightSumWithRoot = rightPathSum + root.val; 
    
    let maxWithRoot = Math.max(leftSumWithRoot, rightSumWithRoot); 
    let maxWithoutRoot = Math.max(leftPathSum, rightPathSum); 
    
    let maxSoFar = Math.max(maxWithRoot, maxWithoutRoot); 
    
    // Case 5: Root with alone
    maxSoFar = Math.max(maxSoFar, root.val); 
    
    // Case 6: Max path goes through the root
    let maxThroughRoot = leftSumWithRoot + rightSumWithRoot - root.val;
    
    return Math.max(maxThroughRoot, maxSoFar);
    
};
```

I am getting some of the test cases passing, some are not, especially the ones which have negative values. I know my algorithm most probably has issues, but can someone help me where my thinking going in the wrong direction. I saw different solutions to this problem. In some solutions, they are comparing the **maxPathSum(node. left) and maxPathSum(node.right) with 0** Is the issue related to this? Also, in some other solutions, they are not considering the maxPathSum that is inside the left and right subtree. Shouldn't I do that? If someone just gives me an idea of where I am doing wrong, I would be really grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the failing testcases? Pasting your code into Leetcode, the failing testcase happens when all values in a tree are negative, but you return 0. Think about what the answer should be if all tree nodes have a negative value.

Comment: @kcsquared You are right. I thought about this but could not figure out how to deal with the 0 unfortunately. Also, Is there anything wrong with the Cases I wrote? Do you see any issues there? By the way, thanks for replying.

Comment: The cases are fine; there's an unstated assumption in the question that paths can't be empty.

Comment: @kcsquared Got it. Although I am not sure I got it properly, I will look into this as you stated. And thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing in this input: `[-2,-1]`

graph looks like this:

```
   -2
   /
 -1
```

So, `let maxWithoutRoot = Math.max(leftPathSum, rightPathSum);` will be 0. Then `maxSoFar`  will be zero so eventaully your output is 0. If I organize your code :

```
var maxPathSum = function(root) {
    let res=root.val
    function dfs(node){
        if (node===null){
            return 0
        }
        let left=dfs(node.left)
        let right=dfs(node.right)
        // ignoring negatives. looking for max, so if left or right is negative, do not add it
        let leftMax=Math.max(left,0)
        let rightMax=Math.max(right,0)
        res=Math.max(node.val+leftMax+rightMax,res)
        return node.val+Math.max(leftMax,rightMax)
    }
    dfs(root)
    return res
};
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have a question. Why are we ignoring the negatives on the left and right subtree? If the tree consists of only negative numbers and we compare the negative value with 0, how will we get the correct result? And in the dfs function, why are we not returning the ```res``` directly?

Comment: @h_a negatives will always decrease the total.